# cannot resolve symbol observableArrayMap

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am following this tutorial on MVVM:
https://medium.com/@husayn.hakeem/android-by-example-mvvm-data-binding-view-model-part-3-3dcd08caf650

Here is the corresponding GitHub repo for the project:
https://github.com/husaynhakeem/TicTacToe-MVVM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/husaynhakeem/io/tictactoe_mvvm/viewmodel/GameViewModel.java

I am working on the GameModelView class, however, the ObservableArrayMap cannot be resolved, not even in the import statement.

Any clue about what the issue is, is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what caused the issue. I had should have added the following to my build.gradle in the app module:

```
android {
...
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}}
```

More at: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start